# How to transfer a list of elements to a pandas dataframe by every three elements?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list

I have a list of people's info and I want to transfer it to a pandas dataframe.
My list:

```
My_lst = ['Name1','Title1','Company1','Name2','Title2','Company2','Name3','Title3','Company3',
'Name4','Title4','Company4','Name5','Title5','Company5','Name6','Title6','Company6'...]
```

Expected outputs:

```
NAME             TITLE              COMPANY
Name1            Title1             Company1
Name2            Title2             Company2
Name3            Title3             Company3
...
```

How do I do that in Python? Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IIUC `reshape`

```
pd.DataFrame(np.array(My_lst).reshape((-1,3)),columns=['name','title','company'])
    name   title   company
0  Name1  Title1  Company1
1  Name2  Title2  Company2
2  Name3  Title3  Company3
3  Name4  Title4  Company4
4  Name5  Title5  Company5
5  Name6  Title6  Company6
```